# cocoapods xcworkspace missing after upgrade to xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Having issues with cocoapods - **Missing .xcworkspace**. I tried to follow the tutorial on Raywenderlich which I have tried before in Xcode 6 and it worked. Since I have upgraded to Xcode 7 just now... xcworkspace is missing even though the pods was installed correctly... I did an update to cocoapods just to be sure if I have missed any important update by still the same problem. This only happened to me after I have updated in Xcode 7.

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Alamofire (1.2.3)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `IceCreamShop.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
```

Comment: You mean the `IceCreamShop.xcworkspace` is not generated?

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your cocoapods:

```
sudo gem update cocoapods
```